# Make flex list items stagger into multiple lines on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to make a css flex list stagger text onto two lines on smaller screens however nothing I've tried seems to work.

I've attempted to use spans and `br` at several different media queries but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is how I would like it to look:

```
                               Text Text Text Text Text 
                                    Text  Text  Text
```

Here is my code

Html

```
<div class="div">
        <h1 class="text-center">List</h1>
        <ul id ="list">
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
          <li>Four</li>
          <li>Five</li>
          <li>Six</li>
          <li>Seven</li>
          <li>Eight</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Css

```
.div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 225px;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  white-space: normal;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.div h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "Helevtica";
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
}
#list li {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -25px;
  color: black;
}

#list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

And here is a [Code pen](http://codepen.io/kgoode517/pen/bpzwOy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this this stylesheet

```
<style>
        .div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 225px;
            background-color: #dbdbdb;
            white-space: normal;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            font-size: 30px;
        }

        .div h1 {
            font-size: 70px;
            color: black;
            font-family: "Helevtica";
            position: relative;
            top: -15px;
        }

        #list li {
            margin-right: 2em;
            position: relative;
            bottom: -25px;
            color: black;
        }

        #list {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: center;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-right: 25px;
        }

    </style>
```

change the margin of the li element as per your requirement and you may also set a min-width to the li elements

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

An initial setting of a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap`. This means that flex items are confined to a single line and will not wrap. You can override this default with `flex-wrap: wrap`.

[**Revised Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpzwPP)

Reference:

- [`flex-wrap` definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) ~ MDN (note the "Initial Value")