# results displayed on two lines?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been working on this project for a bit;

http://www.periodictablesearch.zackreid.com/

If you search 'e' and resize to browser it breaks at a certain point.

Html

```
<div class="resultsdiv">
            <!-- Show Results -->
            <ul id="results"></ul>
        </div>
```

Then the css

```
.resultsdiv{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

ul#results {
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.09);
    height: 120px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    overflow:auto;
        -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 0px 43px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 0px 43px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 0px 43px;
}


ul#results li {
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
  border: aliceblue solid 1px;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Is there anyway that I can make the results go onto an extra line?

Using the css.

Comment: do you use display:flex and flex-wrap:wrap for ul ?  the page is only usable, seeable with chrome, else where white background and color ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37091668/3597276

Comment: Yup, **add** `flex-wrap: wrap` to the `ul` and **remove** `height: 120px` so that it will stretch. You also need to add another browser prefix for the main background gradient: `-moz-radial-gradient`  so that Firefox has a background.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Could you put it as a question so I can mark it correct? Thanks for pointing out the error with FireFox. I always forget about it

Answer (score 1):

Like @GCyrillus says... you can try to add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `ul`.
And in Firefox your web doesn't seem to work very wel...

Here you can find 
[A Complete Guide to FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)